# FrameTicks->Automatic in ClickPane causes constant processor activity

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I discovered that a `MatrixPlot` in a `ClickPane` causes one of my processor cores to cycle at about 50% activity if the option `FrameTicks -> Automatic` is present. I have cut down the code to the following (which doesn't do anything really):

```
a = ConstantArray[0, {2, 11}];
ClickPane[
 Dynamic@
  MatrixPlot[a, FrameTicks -> Automatic],
 # &
 ]
```

[image]

Switching to `FrameTicks -> None` stops the core activity.

[image]

To study the processor behavior I let a `Clock` cycle between `None` and `Automatic` every 20 secs (remove the above ClickPane first):

```
ClickPane[
 Dynamic@
  MatrixPlot[a, FrameTicks -> ft],
 # &
 ]
Dynamic[ft = {Automatic, None}[[Clock[{1, 2, 1}, 20]]]]
```

This gives me the following processor activity display:

[image]

This is on my Win7-64 / MMA 8.0.1 system.

My questions are:

- Is this reproducible on other systems?
- Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?
- Why does the bare `MatrixPlot[a]` (without any `FrameTicks` setting whatsoever) have these odd-looking frame tick choices?

[image]

Comment: Running your code on MacOS-10.6.8/MMA7.0.1.0 student edition, MMA's %cpu varies between ~1% and ~16% with `FrameTicks` set to `None` and `Automatic`, respectively. So, it appears that it has been in the code a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `Automatic` setting of the `FrameTicks` option changes an internal variable that can be seen by `Dynamic`. It is apparently (and I think erroneously) not localized. This causes a complete re-evaluation of the argument of the `Dynamic`.

**A workaround** would be to add `Refresh`, which enables the use of `TrackedSymbols`, so that we can restrict triggering to just the variables we're interested in, in this case array `a` and the `FrameTicks` options value `ft`:

```
ClickPane[
 Dynamic@
  Refresh[
   MatrixPlot[a, FrameTicks -> ft],
   TrackedSymbols -> {a, ft}],
 # &
 ]
Dynamic[ft = {Automatic, None}[[Clock[{1, 2, 1}, 20]]]]
```

My processor status stays flat at close to zero now.

Comment: _In my machine_ this is unrelated to `Automatic`. ft = {{1,2}, None} shows the same behavior.

Comment: @belisarius Indeed, it looks like setting it to anything else than a plain `None` does this...

Comment: @belisarius {All, All} =active, but {All, None}=inactive

Comment: @belisarius It might be, but it is certainly at a low level. Can't see it that well in my performance graph.

Comment: Not here. The results are the same as before. Are you sure you are measuring the kernel activity?

Comment: @belisarius I discovered something more bizarre: ft = {{1, 2}, None} yields an active processor, but if I change the matrix `a` from size 2x11 to 3x3 the activity stops!?!

Comment: @Sjored I am still getting activity with a 3x3 matrix here. But I noticed that _sometimes_ starting a fresh Mma session (front end and kernel) the activity is not there. Really weird bug

Answer (score 4):

Win XP Mma 8.0

[image]

The missed peaks correspond to times when the notebook was hidden by another window. Losing focus does not stop the CPU draining.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed also on Mac OS X 10.6, Mathematica 8.0.1.

I thought at first that this was something to do with the kernel having to recalculate where the ticks went, every time  `FrameTicks->Automatic` option was set.

So I tried this and got the same result. Likewise for `ArrayPlot`.

```
With[{fta = FrameTicks /. 
    FullForm[MatrixPlot[a, FrameTicks -> Automatic]][[1, 4]]},
 ClickPane[Dynamic@MatrixPlot[a, FrameTicks -> ft], # &]
  Dynamic[ft = {fta, None}[[Clock[{1, 2, 1}, 20]]]] ]
```

But not for this plot - CPU usage barely moved between the two states.:

```
ClickPane[
 Dynamic@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> ft], # &]
Dynamic[ft = {Automatic, None}[[Clock[{1, 2, 1}, 20]]]]
```

I can only surmise that there must be some inefficiency in the way `FrameTicks` are displayed on these raster-type plot.

In answer to your third question, the odd tick choice doesn't reproduce on my system.

[image]

Comment: As I understand (I may be wrong here), the exact values for `Ticks->Automatic` option are calculated by the FrontEnd, not by the kernel.